# Why does Launchpad act differently with 64- and 32-bit packages?

Tags: ppa, packaging

I'm making Ubuntu packages from the source code of a geology program. I can make deb packages on my PC, and also Launchpad is able to make binary packages for 32-bit OS.

I noticed a strange behavior of Launchpad. It makes both development (libfoo-dev) and shared library (libfoo) from the uploaded source code for i386 although it makes only binary package for amd64 from same code. Looking at [i386](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/116719990/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.libqgp-core-tools_1.22.0-4_BUILDING.txt.gz) and [amd64](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/116720419/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-amd64.libqgp-core-tools_1.22.0-4_BUILDING.txt.gz) build logs, I found that for amd64 `debian/rules binary-arch` is called instead of `debian/rules binary`. This causes my source not to generate a development package for amd64.

How can I solve this issue? Build logs and package sources are available in `ppa:soroush-r/geopsy-deb` in case you want to take a look.

Comment: Are you sure that you have `Architecture: any` at your `debian/control` file?

Comment: @hakermania Yes. I looked at `debian/control` again. there is `Architecture: any` in both `dev` and lib packages and the `Architecture` field is empty in  `Source` section.

Answer (score 2):

Architecture independent packages (where `Architecture: all` is set in `debian/control`) are only build on one architecture, which is i386 for Ubuntu. Only the architecture depending packages are build on all other architectures. That's why `debian/rules binary` is called on i386, but `debian/rules binary-arch` on amd64, armhf, and powerpc.

You set `Architecture: all` for your -dev packages. This is correct if the -dev package is identical on every architecture. You will see that the .deb package will end with _all.deb instead of _amd64.deb or _i386.deb. The _all.deb will be build on i386, but also used on amd64.

You should change the architecture of the -dev package to `Architecture: any` in `debian/control` if you need different content for the amd64 -dev package. If the -dev package should have the identical content on amd64 than on i386, everything is working correctly and you shouldn't encounter a problem.